# Sybase C library dbbind

Tags: c, sybase

I am using the following in "c" program to copy data from database into a program variable.
I suspect that the data while being copied into the program variable is being transformed to an unexpected value.
Is there a way I can print the value coming from the database and value being copied to the address of the program variable?

dbbind(dbproc,11,DATETIMEBIND,0,&lrowi.ldti.locl_dt);
dbbind(dbproc,12,INTBIND,0,&lrowi.ldti.emp_id);

Comment: Basically,  you just need debug the program and check the value.
BTW ,  can you paste the complete piece of code?

Comment: you can save the value to be returned in a log table and query it later, or use the print statement inside the procedure